# Read input param and passs to sed with xargs

Tags: bash, unix, sed, xargs

I have two files, file 1 and file 2: I want to add a log at the beginning of each function to know from which file it was executed:

**File1:**

```
function one(){
}

function two(){
}
```

**File2**:

```
function one(){
}

function two(){
}
```

I'm trying by listing the files, using `xargs` to send the file to `sed` to find the pattern and add the log after the match

```
ls  file*  | xargs sed  '/function /a $.log("File");'
```

**output:**

```
function one(){
$.log("File");
}

function two(){
$.log("File");
}

function one(){
$.log("File");
}

function two(){
$.log("File");
}
```

Now I need to use the filename as a variable inside `sed`, but in reviewing `xargs --help` and `sed --help` I don't see how to solve this.

Is there a reference to the file that `sed` is processing that can be used within the command? Something like

```
ls  file*  | xargs sed  '/function /a $.log("$INPUT_REFERENCE");'
```

**Expected output:**

```
function one(){
$.log("File1");
}

function two(){
$.log("File1");
}
function one(){
$.log("File2");
}

function two(){
$.log("File2");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're open to using `awk`:

```
awk '
1                                                 # print current line
$1=="function" { print "$.log(\""FILENAME"\");"   # print a $.log() line
}' File*
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
awk '1;$1=="function"{print "$.log(\""FILENAME"\");"}' File*
```

This generates the following for the 2 sample files:

```
function one(){
$.log("File1");
}

function two(){
$.log("File1");
}
function one(){
$.log("File2");
}

function two(){
$.log("File2");
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I need to save the modification, replace the original file with the file with the log. The command you provided with Awk does exactly what I want, but to update the file it seems to me that I need gawk.

Comment: yeah, you could use `-i inplace` but (I think) that option is currently only supported in `GNU awk` (aka `gawk`)

Comment: gawk -i inplace  '1;$1=="function"{print "$.log(\""FILENAME"\");"}' file*    does as expected, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Below code should implement what you need, although I don't fully get the semantics of you're trying to achieve, as `function foo()` code will get overridden by its next declaration (in the same file).
What you're looking for is xargs's `-I <string>`:

```
$ cat foo.sh
function one(){
}

function two(){
}

$ touch File{1..2}

$ ls File* | xargs -I@ sed $'/function /a\$.log("@");' foo.sh
function one(){
$.log("File1");
}

function two(){
$.log("File1");
}

function one(){
$.log("File2");
}

function two(){
$.log("File2");
}
```

Mind above uses GNU sed, if you're using macosx you'll need to use `gsed` there.

Comment: should be able to read the actual files (`File1` and `File2` in OP's case) by replacing `sed ... foo.sh` with `sed ... @`

Comment: I am trying to modify hundreds of files, adding to each function within the file a log with the name of the file. I badly exemplified the problem. But both answers will definitely help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed & parallel):

```
parallel sed -i ''/function/a$.log("{}");'\' {} ::: file[12]
```

Update in place `file1` and `file2`, appending a line after the word `function`.